# HTML + Blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, export, blend4web

The diagram is of a river bank with a formula that can be adjusted with sliders to calculate the river's area, steepness, vegetation population, etc.

The question is, is it possible to do this in blender somehow, either with the game engine or drivers, so that sliders could change not only numerals but also the look of the river diagram?

I have pretty much zero experience with the game engine (but years with anything else to do with Blender) and before trying anything out I wanted to know if it was possible to do something like this.

I have also seen this recent link to the game engine working on browsers and was wondering if this could work for this too?

http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/11/blend4web-an-interactive-3d-viewer/

Comment: Note, that blend4web has nothing to do with the blender game engine. It is an interactive 3D/Game engine itself. For more details check out the manual [http://www.blend4web.com/pub/b4w_manual_en.pdf](http://www.blend4web.com/pub/b4w_manual_en.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like I have some learnin' to do :)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/about.html#browser-webgl-support) Blend4web uses [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/) and supports:

#### Full Support

- Yandex Browser
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera

#### Experimental Support

- Internet Explorer 11
- Safari 8

#### Mobile Platforms

- Android (on the majority of modern devices)
- BlackBerry
- Firefox OS
- iOS 8
- Tizen
- Ubuntu Touch
- WebOS

It looks promising, I would check whether it covers all requirements and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah saw that too, and might be a go'er, time to learn something new :)