# How to play My Blender Game in a webbrowser?

Tags: game-engine, export

Right now I have a .blend file for a little interface project I am working on in the game engine and also a .exe

Is there a way I can play my project in a web browser so I can show it to some friends?

Comment: There were blender plugin for web browsers, but it not supported anymore. You can use http://www.blend4web.com. This question seems to duplication of: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14302/html-blender-game-engine?rq=1